# Setting variables inside Jade templating engine

Tags: node.js, express, pug

It is possible to do something like this?

**layout.jade**

```
title= title
```

**index.jade**

```
extends layout

  title='Foo'
```

So... create a variable in index.jade and use it in layout.jade. Just a plain single variable, **not a block content**.

Not duplicated.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski but that answer use blocks. it's not possible to just set a variable without creating a block, which is generally a group (block) of vars?

Comment: why set variables inside templates?

Comment: You cannot avoid using a **block**. When using `extends` you need to use a **block** https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade-language.md#template-inheritance